python and problems with passing array to a function
I need to solve some ordinary differential equation dy/dx = f(x) = x^2 ln(x) and to proceed I create the array xpt between the limits 0. <= xpt <= 2. Because I have to be careful at xpt = 0, I have defined the function as follows:
def f(x):
    if x <= 1.e-6:
        return 0.
    else:
        return np.square(x)*np.log(x)

My calling programme reads:
Npt = 200

xpt = np.linspace(0.,2.,Npt)

fpt = np.zeros(Npt)

However, when I make the call fpt = f(xpt), I get the error:
"ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

I can get around this by introducing a for loop, writing
for ip in range(Npt):
    fpt[ip] = f(xpt[ip])

But this seems a hack and unsatisfactory.
I have tried to look at the suggestion of using a.any() and redefined the function as
def Newf(x):

    if ((x <= 1.e-6).all()):
        return 0.
    else:
        return np.square(x*np.log(x))

But this seems to give f(0.) as NaN.
Any help on how to proceed gratefully received.

Try this code
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return np.where(x <= 1.e-6, 0., np.square(x) * np.log(x))

Npt = 200
xpt = np.linspace(0., 2., Npt)
fpt = f(xpt)

print(fpt)

np.where(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false) applies the condition element-wise. If the condition is true, it uses value_if_true, otherwise it uses value_if_false.

You wrote the function f as is it's getting a single value, while passing an array to it. I think you also misunderstood the use of .all() and .any() function on np arrays (and other iterables in python).
.any() function returns True if any of the elements in the array are with values that can be considered "True", in the case of a number it checks there is an element that is not 0 in the array. The .all() function acts in a similar fashion, only it makes sure ALL the items are with values that can be interpreted as "True".
A possible solution is to change the function to handle arrays and return a modified array. Not sure what you were planning to do in your code later but I assume you wanted to see if the f(xpt) is all zeros. In this case this should work:
import numpy as np


def f(array):
    return np.where(array <= 1.e-6, 0., np.square(array) * np.log(array))


def main():
    Npt = 200
    xpt = np.linspace(0., 2., Npt)
    print(not any(f(xpt)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Edited f function to use np.where inspired by Ken's answer

scipy can solve the differential equations:
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

def f(y,x):
    if x <= 1e-6:
        return 0.
    else:
        return np.square(x)*np.log(x)

Npt = 200
C = 0.
xpt = np.linspace(0.,2.,Npt)
ypt = sp.integrate.odeint(f, C, xpt)
print(np.hstack((np.atleast_2d(xpt).T,ypt)))

